# Toggle visibility of object on specific hyperlink click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do not know if this issue already got an answer but I have problem regarding toggle visibility of div's after a specific hyperlink click.

My code  [(live example here)](https://jsfiddle.net/6dpmLL4q/1/):

```
<!-- Link 1 -->
<a href="javascript:showSub(1)">test1</a>
<div class="collapse" id="AA1">
    AA 1 display
</div>    
<div class="collapse" id="BB1">
    BB 1 display
</div>    

<!-- Link 2 -->
<a href="javascript:showSub(2)">test2</a>
<div class="collapse" id="AA2">
    AA 2 display
</div>    
<div class="collapse" id="BB2">
    BB 2 display
</div>
```

What I want is that whenever I press the button test1 it will show all the div's containing the `id="AA1"` and `id="BB1"`. If I press another button or the same it should be closed. Something like:

```
function showSub(id){    
    $("AA"+id).toggle();    
    $("BB"+id).toggle();
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

*Please keep in mind that I need this inline javascript call due to dynamic setting of the values within the `showSub(x)` function.*

Comment: use toggleClass method... Look in http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue but  your selectors in the showSub function aren't actually selecting anything, you need to append a pound sign (#) before the AA and BB to indicate you're trying to select ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that without the inline JS. Just add an ID  or class to the link element with a number. Check the fiddle.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/kpot8j5x/2/

JS

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var link = $(this);
    var num = link.attr('id');
    $('#AA'+num+', #BB'+num).toggle();
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id='1'>test1</a><br/>
<div class="collapse" id="AA1">
    AA 1 display
</div>    
<div class="collapse" id="BB1">
    BB 1 display
</div>    

<!-- Link 2 -->
<a href="#" id='2'>test2</a><br/>
<div class="collapse" id="AA2">
    AA 2 display
</div>    
<div class="collapse" id="BB2">
    BB 2 display
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

ID selector needs `#` before the ID, like this `$("#AA1")`.

```js
function showSub(id){    
    $("#AA"+id).toggle();    
    $("#BB"+id).toggle();
}
```

```css
.collapse{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Link 1 -->
<a href="javascript:showSub(1)">test1</a><br/>
<div class="collapse" id="AA1">
    AA 1 display
</div>    
<div class="collapse" id="BB1">
    BB 1 display
</div>    

<!-- Link 2 -->
<a href="javascript:showSub(2)">test2</a>
<div class="collapse" id="AA2">
    AA 2 display
</div>    
<div class="collapse" id="BB2">
    BB 2 display
</div>
```

Comment: ah damn haha I was so close! Thanks for the help!